# as.H2O cannot determine file type error

Tags: r, hdfs, h2o

Hello I am trying to get some twitter data into a h2o random forest model in R. I keep getting a cannot determine file type error. I am in R version 1.1.453 using Rstudio.

code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ace)
library(h2o)
library(data.table)

hdfs.kinit()
h2oStart()

tweet.dt <- as.data.table(fread(file = "/tech/home/js87549e/ExtractedTweets.csv", col.names = c('Party','Handle','Tweet')))
tweet.dt$outcome <- 0
tweet.dt$outcome[tweet.dt$Party == "Democrat"] <- 1
tweet.dt$outcome <- as.factor(tweet.dt$outcome)
tweet.dt$Tweet <- as.character(tweet.dt$Tweet)

inp.dt <- as.data.table(tweet.dt %>%
  mutate(string = strsplit(Tweet, split = " ")) %>%
  unnest(string))

inp.dt$string <- as.factor(inp.dt$string)

dat.dt <- as.data.table(inp.dt[,c(4,5)])

inp.hex <- as.h2o(dat.dt)
```

Data: https://www.kaggle.com/kapastor/democratvsrepublicantweets/downloads/democratvsrepublicantweets.zip/4

ERROR MESSAGE:

Cannot determine file type. for /tech/appl/user/js87549e/tmp/RtmpdvNc9d/file2cef348f3bde4.csv_sid_9333_9

Comment: what version of h2o are you using? I ran your code with one of the newer versions of h2 (version 3.20.0.3 ) and was not able to reproduce your issue, as.h2o was able to convert your frame to an h2o frame.

Comment: I am running in 3.18.0.11

Comment: I would try updating to the latest version and seeing if you still have the same issue.